# is there any way to setup s3 bucket to get append to the existing object for each run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

We have a requirement to append to the existing S3 object, when we run the spark application every hour. I have tried this code:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("name").mode("append").option("compression", "gzip").parquet("s3n://path")
```

This application is creating new parquet files for every run. Hence, I am looking for a workaround to achieve this requirement.

Question is:

How we can configure the S3 bucket to get append to the existing object?

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible to append to objects** in Amazon S3. They can be overwritten, but not appended.

There is apparently a sneaky method where a file can be multi-part copied, with the 'source' set to the file and then set to some additional data. However, that cannot be accomplished in the method you show.

If you wish to add additional data to an External Table (eg used by EMR or Athena), then simply **add an additional file in the correct folder** for the desired partition.

Comment: that's quite a devious trick. I like it. But as all but the last partition must be > 5MB, it will only work for files bigger than that. Anyway, Columnar formats don't like being appended to in a separate query either. These are not CSV files.